# ¿Como puedo hacer que mi servicio sea HTTPS?

Tags: java, webservice, rest, https

estoy intentando que la ruta "http://localhost:8080/proxy-hcv/resthcv" que genera el WADL de mi servicio REST aparezca como HTTPS en lugar de HTTP. 
¿Sabéis como puedo modificar esto?

```
<resources base="http://localhost:8080/proxy-hcv/resthcv">
  <resource path="/">
    <resource path="generarCSV">
      <method name="POST">
        <request>
          <param name="totalCsv" style="query" default="1" type="xs:int"/>
        </request>
        <response>
         <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
        </response>
      </method>
  </resource>
</resource>
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puedes crear un certificado ssl autofirmado, aunque los navegadores te mostrarán una alerta, te puede sacar de apuros en ambientes de pruebas o en una red interna... pero lo ideal es que compres un certificado ssl con una entidad certificadora. Si vas a alojar la aplicación en un hosting, tienes opciones gratuitas como let´s encrypt.

Comment: Pues depende cómo estés generando tu servicio. Está en un contenedor Tomcat? Spring boot? Weblogic? Puedes ponerle el certificado al contenedor/servidor. También puedes poner por delante un haproxy / nginx/apache que redirija las peticiones y que sea el que sirva todo con HTTPS, haciendo proxy reverso con tu contenedor / servidor.

Answer (score -1):

Te sugiero visitar el siguiente enlace, ayuda bastante en cuestión de este tema, solo sigue las indicaciones que encuentres.
[Enlace aqui](https://punchsalad.com/ssl-certificate/install-lets-encrypt-godaddy/)

Terminando las indicaciones tendrías un resultado como este.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Las respuestas que sólo son un enlace se consideran de baja calidad. Si esa página desaparece, le cambian la URL o el dominio lo compra una tienda de mascotas, tu respuesta ya no le va a servir a otros que tengan la misma prgeunta. Procura poner EN tu respuesta los puntos importantes del procedimiento que le recomiendas seguir